# how to disable active toggle on bootstrap button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, buttongroup

I like bootstrap button group style, I don't like the active toggle. I can't disable the active state, unless I click out of the button.

How can I disable the button toggle?

[can't find active class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJhkG.png)

```html
<div class="btn-group" aria-label="..." style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="import_all_db(this)">import_all_db</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="import_all_qcloud(this)">import_all_qcloud</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="import_all(this)">import_all</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS declaration you are looking for is `.focus`, `:focus` :

```css
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090;
    border-color: #122b40;
}
```

overrule that if you want to change it - as in the example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w7rzqLz3/** - you could set it to have the same `background-color` and `border-color` as the other states.